# Sed Every X lines, GREP between Y Lines

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that basically contains arrangements of values as presented below (I have numbered the lines.)

```
! MATCH       1
!             2
HIT           3
NUM     1     4
VAL A  82     5
LEU A 144     6
ALA A 154     7
VAL A 333     8
ALA A 334     9
PHE A 372     10
END           11
!             12
```

I am trying to create a file that contains all the instances in which these value blocks contain PHE in line 10 like above (as opposed to ALA or VAL, etc).

**short example of multiple value blocks in a file:**

```
! MATCH 
!
HIT 
NUM     1
VAL A 184
PHE A 209
END 
!
! MATCH
!
HIT
NUM     1
LEU A 296
ILE A 321
END 
!
! MATCH
!
HIT 
NUM     1
LEU A 296
PHE A 321
END 
!
```

My code attempting to do this is:

```
sed -n '23~12p' file.txt | grep -B 9 -A 2 PHE > newfile.txt
```

Basically, starting at line 23, skip every 12 lines (so as to look only at line 10 of the value block), then grep the previous 9 lines and subsequent 2 if PHE is present in line 10 of the value block.

However, as I'm sure you can tell, the code above outputs only the previous lines in the sed output.

```
sed -n '23~12p' file.txt | grep -B 9 -A 2 PHE file.txt > newfile.txt
```

But if I add the file (file.txt) for grep, it ignores the sed output and instead greps the previous lines, even when PHE is not in the tenth line of the value block.

IE:

```
ILE A 222
END
!
! MATCH
!
HIT
NUM     1
ILE A 605
ILE A 620
PHE A 644   <--- What grep is matching
VAL A 633
ALA A 634
```

I'm a little confused as to how to write this script to search for PHE at the position I'm looking for (position 10), looking for it every 12 lines, and grepping the entire value block (the previous 9 lines and the subsequent 2 lines) only if PHE is found in position 10.

Would gladly appreciate any advice! Thank you!

Comment: If you are doing more than simple substution (which you are), you really should be using `awk` or `Perl`. Consider adding those tags.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Will do, thank you!

Comment: When your real input has multiple block,s you should provide sample input that has multiple blocks, typically 3. Each block doesn't have to be 12 lines long - make each, say, 5 lines and solve for that then expand the solution to work for 12. Include blocks that do and don't match and also provide the expected output.

Comment: How are your blocks separated? Blank line? OR just that last line with only `!`?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, added it!

Comment: @zdim Just the !, just added an example above.

Comment: Thank you, updated my answer.  I'd recommend to add a separator when writing that file, and an empty line is good for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk '
    { recLine = NR%8 }
    { rec = (recLine==1 ? "" : rec ORS) $0 }
    recLine==6 { f = /PHE/ }
    (recLine==0) && f { print rec }
' file
! MATCH
!
HIT
NUM     1
VAL A 184
PHE A 209
END
!
! MATCH
!
HIT
NUM     1
LEU A 296
PHE A 321
END
!
```

Just change 8 to 12 and 6 to 10 for your real data.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

I understand what the other lines are doing, but I'm confused as to what this line does:

`{ rec = (recLine==1 ? "" : rec ORS) $0 }`

Could you kindly elaborate on this?

Comment: it sets the `rec` variable to the value of the first line of the record, and appends the current line to `rec` otherwise, thus storing every 12 lines in `rec`. If the syntax is confusing - it's a [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the blocks are separated by an empty line

```
perl -00 -wne'print if (split /\n/)[9] =~ /^PHE/' data.txt
```

See [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for command line switches. Here `-00` splits input in paragraphs, and then each is available to the program under `''` in the [special variable `$_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_). That is [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on newline and the tenth line checked with a regex on whether it starts with `PHE`. If yes, we print the whole block.

---

It is clarified that there are no dedicated block separators; blocks just come one after another, each starting with the `! MATCH` line and ending with the `!` line.

Then the above can't easily keep the whole blocks after filtering since the `$/` of `!`, which can be set by `-0\x21` switch, would introduce spurious input records. Instead, process line by line.

Using the data sample added in the question update

```
perl -ne'
    if (/^\! MATCH/ or eof) { $b[5]=~/^PHE/ and print for @b; @b=() };
    push @b, $_
' data.txt
```

Each line is added to the buffer (or "block") `@b`.  Lines starting with `! MATCH` start a new block, so print the previous one if its 6th line starts with `PHE` (in real data `$b[9]`) and empty the buffer for the next block.

The `eof` is needed so to do this at the end of input as well, for the last block/buffer.

May I suggest to introduce a blank line between records when writing this file.

Comment: Tried the new code, this worked as well! Thank you for the explanation! I agree with introducing a blank line; unfortunately, I'm feeding this data into an old program that is very specific for `!`, so I have to work within this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easily understood and extensible script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
my $matchNum=0;
my @match;
while (<STDIN>) {
  chomp;
  if (/^! MATCH$/) {
    @match and checkMatch(\@match, \$matchNum);
    @match=($_);
  } else { push @match, $_ }
}
@match and checkMatch(\@match, \$matchNum);

sub checkMatch {
  my ($matchAR, $matchNumSR) = @_;
  ++$$matchNumSR;
  if ( $matchAR->[9] =~ /^PHE/ ) {
    print "Match $$matchNumSR = $matchAR->[9]\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '14~12{h;b};H;23~12{/^PHE/!{x;z;x}};25~12{x;/^\n/!p;x}' file
```

Set the grep-like option `-n`. Starting at the 14th line and modulo 12 thereafter, set the hold space to the current line and break out of the sed script. For all other lines, append the current line to the hold space. At line 23 and modulo 12 thereafter, check the current line to begin `PHE` and if not clear the hold space. At line 25 and modulo 12 thereafter, check the hold space and if it does not begin with a newline, print all 12 lines in the hold space.

N.B. If at line 23 and modulo 12 and thereafter, the current line does not begin `PHE` the hold is cleared and subsequent lines appended. The appended lines, are prepended with a newline and therefore if the hold space begins with a newline, the check for `PHE` failed and these lines can be discarded.

An alternative:

```
sed -r '1,13d;:a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/12;Ta;/^([^\n]*\n){9}PHE/p;d' file
```

Delete the first 13 lines. Gather up 12 lines and print them if the 10th line begins `PHE`.